# installshield launch exe from source media

Tags: installation, installshield

I have an installshield msi project that produces CD-ROM files.

I know how to set a custom action in order to launch an exe file stored in binary table.

What i want to do is to launch an exe file that is at the source media root directory and it is not copied at the installation directory.

I do not want to add it at the binary table because i want to be able to change the file without building again the installer.

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: When do you want to run this custom action - just first time install, or also maintenance (say if a related feature is installed later), and/or during uninstallation?

Comment: Althougth i think that what you are asking is irrelevant, the exe file should be launched during the installation after files installed.

Comment: During anything other than first-time installation, files next to the original .msi file may not be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first time installation, you can reference a property that indicates the location of the installation files. Common ones to consider include:

- [SETUPEXEDIR](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/SETUPEXEDIR.htm)
- [SOURCEDIR](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/IHelpPropReference.htm#wp1021299)
- [OriginalDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370562.aspx) - watch out for the .msi filename being included here.

For InstallScript installations (instead of Windows Installer based ones), there is also [PACKAGE_LOCATION](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/Subsystems/installshield19langref/helplibrary/PACKAGE_LOCATION.htm).